# How does an Update Server verify that the request sent was the intended application?

Tags: security, webserver

If you have an update service that's running on a server listening for connections on some random port, how could one verify that any requests coming into that port are from the specific application that I create?

For instance, how does Microsoft know that when Windows checks for an update, it is coming from Windows XP/Vista/7 instead of someone sending it malformed packets?

Comment: Why would it care? If something is broken, what difference does it make what you send it? It won't do the right thing no matter what anyway.